# Detecting and preventing changing of links when page is rendered on browser

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, puppeteer

I want to translate a website and render it on my domain. Here is the flow:

```
URL entered ---> Server ----> Extract text --> Call made to Google's machine translation API
                                                     |
                                                     |
                                                    \ /
   Send back the translated HTML <--  Replace all text in source website with translated
```

This is the flow right now. Is this how everyone would attempt this? I use puppeteer to render the web page before extracting the text.

I am facing a situation for which I do not have the answer. Here is what happens; When the translated HTML is sent back a certain section of it looks as follows:

```
....
<img src="https://chat.amplify.ai/plugin/img/closeme-v2.png" alt="Close">
....
```

Something happens during the rendering that this URL gets changed to `http://localhost:3001/plugin/img/closeme-v2.png` where the hostname is my localhost address (testing on my local machine)

My question is, how do I detect and prevent this? What happens as a result of this is, that the images do not load because the address gets changed.

Is there any event in Javascript that will let me handle this?

Comment: _“Something happens during the rendering”_ - I am guessing, we are probably just talking about the normal process of resolving a _relative_ URL …? If you serve the document from a different base URL now, then of course that also changes how all relative URLs resolve. You will either have to modify all locations in the code accordingly, or insert a `base` element into the document that sets the appropriate base URL to use for resolving relative URLs.

Comment: @CBroe I added the `base` element,  but it did not work. When must the locations be modified? Is there any event?

Comment: @CBroe Could we discuss this here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217368/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-62769453-detecting-and-preventing-changing-of